# Do I need to use a selector with jQuery .load()?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
function callback_function(a,b,c) {
    var aa = a;
    var bb = b;
    $('#content').html("xxx");
}

$('#content').load(href, "", function (a, b, c) { callback_function(a, b, c) });
```

What I want to do is to put the value "xxx" into the html of the `div#content`. Can someone explain how to do this? I think it will work with the code in the callback_function but then if that works then will the actual `.load()` also put some data into `#content`?

Do I even need something to the left of the `.load()` if I am doing everything in the `callback_function()`. I hope this makes sense. Please note it's not production ready. I realize I need to rename parameters, do error checks and such.d

Please note I want to use **.load** not .ajax. as I am using the following wrapper. Sorry in advance that it's a lot of code:

```
$.fn.loadWithEffect = function()
{
    // Add effect layer
    this.addEffectLayer({
        message: $.fn.loadWithEffect.defaults.message
    });

    // Rewrite callback function
    var target = this;
    var callback = false;
    var args = $.makeArray(arguments);
    var index = args.length;
    if (args[2] && typeof args[2] == 'function')
    {
        callback = args[2];
        index = 2;
    }
    else if (args[1] && typeof args[1] == 'function')
    {
        callback = args[1];
        index = 1;
    }

    // Custom callback
    args[index] = function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // Get the effect layer
        var refElement = getNodeRefElement(this);
        var layer = $(refElement).next('.loading-mask');
        var span = layer.children('span');

        // If success
        if (textStatus == 'success' || textStatus == 'notmodified')
        {
            // Initial callback
            if (callback)
            {
                callback.apply(this, arguments);
            }

            // Remove effect layer
            layer.stop(true);
            span.stop(true);
            var currentMarginTop = parseInt(span.css('margin-top'));
            var marginTop = parseInt(span.css('margin-top', '').css('margin-top'));
            span.css({'marginTop':currentMarginTop+'px'}).animate({'opacity':0, 'marginTop':(marginTop-40)+'px'}, {
                'complete': function()
                {
                    layer.fadeAndRemove();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            span.addClass('error').html($.fn.loadWithEffect.defaults.errorMessage+'<br><a href="#">'+$.fn.loadWithEffect.defaults.retry+'</a> / <a href="#">'+$.fn.loadWithEffect.defaults.cancel+'</a>');
            span.children('a:first').click(function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();

                // Relaunch request
                $.fn.load.apply(target, args);

                // Reset
                span.removeClass('error').html($.fn.loadWithEffect.defaults.message).css('margin-left', '');
            });
            span.children('a:last').click(function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();

                // Remove effect layer
                layer.stop(true);
                span.stop(true);
                var currentMarginTop = parseInt(span.css('margin-top'));
                var marginTop = parseInt(span.css('margin-top', '').css('margin-top'));
                span.css({'marginTop':currentMarginTop+'px'}).animate({'opacity':0, 'marginTop':(marginTop-40)+'px'}, {
                    'complete': function()
                    {
                        layer.fadeAndRemove();
                    }
                });
            });

            // Centering
            span.css('margin-left', -Math.round(span.outerWidth()/2));
        }
    };

    // Redirect to jQuery load
    $.fn.load.apply(target, args);

    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `load()` use `ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
   url : href,
   success:function(data){
      callback_function(a, b, c) });
    }
})
```

Comment: Please I would like to use load for other reasons.

Comment: @Angela there is no point in using `load` if you are not loading into a dom element....

Comment: Thanks Neal but I am actually using a wrapper that use load. I can't change the wrapper. I just need to know how to set up the arguments to load as these are the same as the wrapper args.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code so you do not do the selection twice:

```
function callback_function(a,b,c) {
    var aa = a;
    var bb = b;
    $(this).html("xxx"); //<-- key!
}

$('#content').load(href, callback_function);
```

or use `.ajax` instead of `.load`:

```
function callback_function(a,b,c) {
    var aa = a;
    var bb = b;
    $("#content").html("xxx"); 
}
$.ajax({
   url : href,
   success: callback_function
});
```

Comment: Sorry some part of my original question was missed as someone came in an edited it while I was trying to explain more. What I was trying to say was that I'm using a wrapper that calls the following: // Redirect to jQuery load:   $.fn.load.apply(target, args); Do you think I could just change the wrapper to use .ajax instead?

Comment: @Angela what is this _mysterious_ "wrapper" and what are you using it for?

Comment: The wrapper is a bit too long to include here. It's used to make visible a "loading" message on a users screen. part of a template I am using. I could maybe copy that wrapper code and substitute in ajax instead of .load

Comment: I just updated the question with the wrapper code. Hope this is not going too much out of scope of the question.